# Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request does not work in php REPL

Tags: php, symfony

For some reason, this code when in a file

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
var_dump(new Request);
```

works and prints:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)#3 (23) {
  ["attributes"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#5 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["request"]=>
...
```

but in REPL (`php -a`) it spits out an error:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
php > use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
php > var_dump(new Request);

Warning: Uncaught Error: Class 'Request' not found in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1
```

I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` statements seem to affect only the current "command" and are not recognized after it has been executed.

Single command:

```
php > use Foo\Bar\Baz; var_dump(Baz::class);
string(11) "Foo\Bar\Baz"
```

Two commands:

```
php > use Foo\Bar\Baz;
php > var_dump(Baz::class);
string(3) "Baz"
```

You can delay the execution by wrapping it in a namespace, for example:

```
php > namespace Qux {
php { use Foo\Bar\Baz;
php { var_dump(Baz::class);
php { }
string(11) "Foo\Bar\Baz"
php >
```